# Template is missing: Missing template layouts/site with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[],

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

When I tried to go the registration page of my rails site this is what showed up:

> ### Template is missing
>
> Missing template layouts/site with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],
>   :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby,
>   :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/Vanessa/rails_space/app/views" *
>   "C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0/app/views" *
>   "C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.0/app/views"

Here is my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= @title %></title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "site" %>
  </head>
 <body>

  <div id="whole_page">

 <div id="header">RailsSpace</div>
 <div id="nav">

  <%= link_to_unless_current "Home", :action => "index" %> |
  <%= link_to_unless_current "About Us" , :action => "about" %> |
  <%= link_to_unless_current "Help", :action => "help" %>

    </div>
    <div id="content">
   <%= yield %>
      </div>
     </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Here is my user_controller.rb file:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
   layout "site"

    def index
     end

  def register
   @title = "Register"
     end
   end
```

Here is my app/views/user/register.html.erb file:

```
<h2>Register</h2>
<%= form_for :user do |form| %>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Enter Your Details</legend>
  <div class="form_row">
  <label for="screen_name">Screen name:</label>
  <%= form.text_field :screen_name %>
</div>

<div class="form_row">
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<%= form.text_field :email %>
</div>

<div class="form_row">
 <label for="password">Password:</label>
 <%= form.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="form_row">
<%= submit_tag "Register!", :class => "submit" %>
</div>
 </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

I have no idea why its showing this. Someone please help. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Where is your layouts/site file?

Comment: What source code files should I include along with my question? Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi I dont have a layouts/site file. I just have a layouts folder and a site folder, but there is no site file inside either folder. Do you have any other file recommendations? Thanks. @hashrocket

Comment: In your user_controller.rb file, comment out the `layout "site"` line and see what happenes.

Comment: Hey thanks that actually did the trick. @hashrocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user_controller.rb file, you're stating that you want to use a `site` layout file. For this to work, you have to have a file in your layouts directory called site.html.erb (or something close to this if you're using something other than `erb` as your templating language). It should be in the same directory as your `application.html.erb` file. Your error says you are missing that file.

Your other option is to comment out or remove the `layout "site"` line and go with the default layout file, which is `application.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not providing a template to render when your action is hit.
For example:
If your controller is `registrations_controller` and your action is `register_user`, then you must have `register_user.html.erb` in your `/app/views/registrations/` directory.

If that doesn't help, you might want to provide some of your code to be able to understand the issue better.

Comment: Hi I just edited my question providing some code as you suggested, I posted my `application.html.erb`, my `user_controller.rb`, and my `register.html.erb` files. Is there any specific source code files that you recommend I post as well? Thanks.  @noordean